# User field for number cases owned by a user

Tags: case, user, visualforce

I would like some help where when a user owns a case and I want to go to their user page and see how many cases the user currently owns.

Comment: You can accomplish this with a report, FYI. If you need this information on the User object, then you need to create a custom rollup summary using apex or install Rollup Helper from the AppExchange

Comment: Do you want only the number of cases or the details of those cases to appear on the user page?

Comment: I would like to the number of cases.

Answer (score 1):

This utility will assist you with performing this function:

1. Create  a field on the user record to store the value
2. Implement this code
3. Use OwnerID on case for the Case lookup field
4. User ID on user from the User lookup field
   **Note: they do not have to be lookup fields, they just need to be ID fields

Then every time a case is created use a trigger to run the code and the counts will be rolled up to the User record

CODE HERE:

http://www.anthonyvictorio.com/salesforce/roll-up-summary-utility/